# What subsystems in Linux do their own management of physical pages?

Tags: linux-kernel, memory

[Operating System Concepts](https://studfiles.net/preview/6129020/page:119/) says

> Two **other** main subsystems in Linux do their own management of physical
>   pages: the page cache and the virtual memory system.

I was wondering what the subsystems in Linux besides the "two other main subsystems" do their own management of physical pages?

Comment: The link you put is not valid: http://Two%20other%20main%20subsystems%20in%20Linux%20do%20their%20own%20management%20of%20physical%20pages:%20the%20page%20cache%20and%20the%20virtual%20memory%20system.%20T

Comment: This is just a guess, but I imagine that the EFI subsystem probably does, as it has to manipulate page tables when calling EFI services.  Same likely goes for the ACPI subsystem.